# Unlock levels in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, levels

I'd like to make a system that unlock the next level after completing one. 
I'm using c# to code

If you complete level 1, you unlock level2 etc...

mainmenu is build level 0 and the level select is build level 1, so the first level is actually build level 2.

```
public bool isLevel1;
public bool isLevel2;
public bool isLevel3;
public bool isLevel4;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
void OnMouseUp()
{
    if (isLevel1)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(2);
    }
    if (isLevel2)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(3);
    }
    if (isLevel3)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(4);
    }
    if (isLevel4)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(5);
    }
}
```

that's how I select the levels from the level select. i had something similar on the mainmenu, but I don't have a clue how to lock them and then unlock then after completing a level. I had a way to lock them, but i abandoned that since it didn't work. it'd be a big help if somebody could explain it simple enough or point me to a guide that i missed. because i found a few guides, but they assumed i did my level seleciton different, i think.
I thank you in advance and i'm willing to answer any further questions

Comment: While a good question, this is far too broad for a QA site. Please go to gamedev or forum.unity3d, or similar.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that `PlayerPrefs` is probably the best bet for doing something like this, it works well for saving scores for the player so saving unlocked levels could work too.

Here's some documentation for `PlayerPrefs`:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

And here is a good video link showing similar to what you want to achieve :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uw0kZ72zCvE&feature=youtu.be

Comment: For a small game with little-to-no save data, PlayerPrefs would be fine, IMO.  For each level, you could include a bool in PlayerPrefs indicating whether or not it's unlocked.

However, it's worthwhile to note PlayerPrefs isn't really intended for saving game-state data.  It's more for preferences like audio volume, control-mappings, etc. So, if your game has save/load files, or multiple games can be saved to the same computer, you should eventually look at saving game data in a separate file.

Comment: What is the difference between game-state data and audio volume? PlayerPrefs are fine for the intended purpose. There is no need to consider a bool for each level, just an integer defining what the top level: int level = PlayerPrefs.GetInteger("Level",0); if more info needed, using a JSON string is more appropriate. You can have a look at this https://unitygem.wordpress.com/leaderboard-and-saving-data/

Comment: i followed the video, but every line is wrong because I was working with c# and he was with JS. I didn't mention it before that I use c#, but i changed that in the post. sorry for wasting your time

Comment: Try this: http://www.thegamecontriver.com/2014/09/create-level-lock-unlock-system-unity-46.html All it takes is a quick google

Answer (score 0):

Maybe include a script on some empty game object (make sure you call [`Object.DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) so the object remains when levels change), and each time you complete a level, change a boolean variable in that empty object to signify that the level has been completed at least once. Then, unlock the next level in your UI if the `boolean` signifying the previous level has been completed is `true`.

If your character automatically advances to the next level after completing the previous one you could instead use [`OnLevelWasLoaded(int level)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnLevelWasLoaded.html). `level` in this case is the number of the level that was just loaded (so for you 3 would be your real first level). And then change the `boolean` variables of the empty game object in this function instead of at the end of the previous level. This could be most useful if, when you finish the level, there are different levels you could advance to next (there isn't just one option to unlock).